# "fatal error: asm/early_ioremap.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

why am I getting  "fatal error: asm/early_ioremap.h: No such file or directory"  while building simple hello world kernel driver for x86_64 with Linux 4.4.15 libraries using gcc-4.8.5? gcc is searching for asm/early_ioremap.h  which is not available in Linux 4.4.15.
any idea how can i fix this?

```
/opt/gcc-4.8.5-glibc-2.21-p8/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -M -MP -MT '/home/obj/src/kernel/hello_world/hello.o' -MT '/home/obj/src/kernel/hello_world/hello.d' -MT 'hello.E' -MT 'hello.S' -I/home/src/kernel/hello_world -I/home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include -I/home/src/inc -I/home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DPACKET_LEAK_TRACING -DSIZEOF_CPU_REGISTER=8 -DNUM_DEV_CF=0 -DNUM_DEV_USB=0  -mtune=nocona  -march=nocona  -m64 -pipe  -std=gnu89 -g -nostdinc  -isystem /opt/gcc-4.8.5-glibc-2.21-p8/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include -O2   -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -ffreestanding -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wdisabled-optimization -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-int -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-noreturn  -Wundef -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-unused-parameter -Winline -mcmodel=kernel  -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -fno-stack-protector -mno-red-zone -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -imacros generated/autoconf.h   hello.c  -I/home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include/uapi/  -I/home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/uapi/  
In file included from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/realmode.h:5:0,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/acpi.h:33,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/fixmap.h:19,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/apic.h:12,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/smp.h:12,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone_64.h:10,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone.h:4,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include/linux/mmzone.h:856,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from /home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from hello.c:1:
/home/obj/src/kernel/linux-4.4.15/arch/x86/include/asm/io.h:43:31: fatal error: asm/early_ioremap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/early_ioremap.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

> gcc is searching for asm/early_ioremap.h which is not available in Linux 4.4.15.
>
> any idea how can i fix this?

I think you've answered your own question; either you figure out where the functionality contained in that header file has moved, or with what it has been replaced, or you use a Linux 4.4.15-compatible hello world module, or you use an older kernel.

Personally, I'd go for trying out another example that is supposed to work with recent versions of Linux.

Comment: where can I find the hello world relevant to 4.4.15 ? my example is pretty simple. just usage few headers and simple init,exit function.     #include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

Comment: is there any issue in my gcc include param. I am cross-compiling this module.

Comment: @Ravi you said the header file was not available for 4.4.15, so I guess that if that is true, no, there's nothing wrong with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a very similar error just recently trying to build a module from the kernel to an out-of-tree output by specifying the O= flag.

It seems to be that this is the part causing the failure for me

```
make \
    -j1 \
    -C /lib/modules/4.17.9-041709-generic/build \
    M=/home/kbingham/sources/linux/drivers/media/usb/uvc \
    O=/tmp/build-uvc \
    V=1 \
    modules
```

fails,
with the error:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.9-041709-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/io.h:44:10: fatal error: asm/early_ioremap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/early_ioremap.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

whilst

```
make \
    -j1 \
    -C /lib/modules/4.17.9-041709-generic/build \
    M=/home/kbingham/sources/linux/drivers/media/usb/uvc \
    V=1 \
    modules
```

suceeds.